# Implementing a custom column sorting

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, sorting, datagrid

I'm having issues implementing a custom sort on a datagrid column.  Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to create a custom sort for column so that the strings are sorted by length first, then by their values.  It reaches my custom made function, hits the "Throws not implemented line", and then gives me an InvalidOperationException error.

```
Private Sub customSorting(sender As Object, e As DataGridSortingEventArgs) Handles grid.Sorting

    If e.Column.Header = "Test" Then
        Dim comp As IComparer = New RowComparer(e.Column.SortDirection)
        Dim lcv As ListCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(grid.ItemsSource)
        lcv.CustomSort = comp
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Class RowComparer
    Implements System.Collections.IComparer
    Private o As Integer = 0 

    Public Sub New(order As Integer)
        o = order
    End Sub

    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
        If x.ToString.Length > y.ToString.Length Then
            If o = 0 Then
                Return 1
            Else
                Return -1
            End If
        ElseIf x.ToString.Length < y.ToString.Length Then
            If o = 0 Then
                Return -1
            Else
                Return 1
            End If
        Else
            Return String.Compare(x, y)
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual studios automatically generated the 'Throw New NotImplementedException()' which was stopping my program.